# Get-ADUser over entire forest?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I need to update some attributes of user's AD account using `Set-ADUser`, but the user is identified via email, and I don't know which of my forest's domains he's in.

Let's say my forest is `example.com`, with domains `south.example.com`, `north`, `east` and `west`. The emails are per-color, like `red.example.com` (`white.`, `pink.`, etc.).

Just reading attributes works if I query global catalog (`Get-ADUser -server east.example.com:3268`), but resulting object cannot be used for `Set-ADUser` (since, duh, global cat is read-only).

Is there any other option than ladder of ifs on consecutive domains? Which is 1) ugly, 2) might miss other domains that I'm not aware of (don't ask, it's complicated).

I tried `Get-ADUser -server example.com` (querying root domain) - it worked last week, doesn't work anymore and I have no idea why - there's no error message, the object just comes up empty.

Comment: Let’s see some code and we can begin to help.

Comment: But I gave examples  of what I'm doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so Get-ADUser over forest works as specified above - but since I originally wanted to do Set-ADUser using the object from search, I have to write a bit more code.

See, Get-ADUser returns "server-agnostic" object, which means that using this object for Set-ADUser requires providing -Server if the user is in a different domain that you.

Resulting code:

```
(Get-ADForest).domains |% { 
    $tmpUser = Get-ADUser -Server $_ -Filter {EmailAddress -eq $Mail}
    if ($tmpUser) { 
        $user = $tmpUser
        $server = $_
        $tmpUser = $null
    }
} 

$user | Set-ADUser -Certificates @{Add=$newCert} -server $server
```

Not nearly as nice, but it WORKS.

Answer (score 2):

There are many examples on the web for this use case... Just search for them using you post title.

Example(s):

[Powershell to list all users from domains in forest](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28551317/Powershell-to-list-all-users-from-domains-in-forest.html)

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
(Get-ADForest).domains | 
% {
    Get-ADUser -filter * -SearchBase "OU=Accounts,$((Get-ADDomain -Server $_).distinguishedname)" -Server $_ | 
    Select Name,sAMAccountName | Export-CSV "C:\$_ User Accounts.csv" -nti
}
```

See also the samples here:

[PowerShell Code: Find User in Active Directory Forest](https://adsecurity.org/?p=354)

[How to query user across multiple forest with AD powershell](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/a36ae19f-ab38-4e5c-9192-7feef103d05f/how-to-query-user-across-multiple-forest-with-ad-powershell)

Comment: I swear to you that I spent a couple days searching for that, apparently I was asking all the wrong questions... Now I just have to test if I can Set-ADUser will work with an object found using this method. Thanks anyway!

Comment: No worries. It happens, and sometimes it's just a matter of breaking the question in to pieces, or string quoting pieces of the question for more exact matches. Pick up the book, 'Google Hacking', it has lots of tricks. Much of it works across the different search engines, and when looking for tech stuff, I use DuckDuckGo, as it seems to deliver the best tech results for me. Once I find interesting things, while looking for something specific, I always save it for later use. It's my search data hoarding OCD stuff.  ;-} --- TB's of it over the years.

Comment: My Google Fu is usually up to task, seems my mistake was concentrating on "Get-ADUser entire forest" instead of more generic query :-)

Comment: To close the topic, this is what I needed: (Get-ADForest).domains |% { Get-ADUser -Server $_ -Filter {EmailAddress -eq $Mail} -Property Certificates}

Answer (score -1):

Much easier: Just ask the global catalog.

```
Get-ADUser -Server <your_globalcatalg_server>:<your_globalcatalog_port> -Filter {EmailAddress -eq $Mail}
```

Global catalog default port is 3268, so usually this works:

```
Get-ADUser -Server global_catalog_server.domain:3268 -Filter {EmailAddress -eq $Mail}
```

Of course, if you need to *modify* the user after finding it, you need to run Set-ADUser against a normal LDAP service, because global catalog is read-only. You can, for example, get the user's domain from the CanonicalName property and then find a domain controller like so:

```
(Get-ADDomain 'domain').InfrastructureMaster
```

Edit 2023-10-30: Here is a full example:

```
$user = Get-ADUser -Server global_catalog_server.domain:3268 -Filter {EmailAddress -eq 'john.doe@example.com'} -Properties CanonicalName
Set-ADUser -Identity $user.SAMAccountName -Server (Get-ADDomain $user.CanonicalName.Substring(0, $user.CanonicalName.IndexOf('/'))).InfrastructureMaster -Certificates @{Add=$newCert}
```

Comment: Literally the first sentence of my question says "I need to update (...)". The entire point of this question was that Get-ADUser using global catalogue wasn't working for me.

Comment: My point was that its not necessary to query all the child domains and foreach through them just to find your user(s), as both the answers above show. I usually do this in two lines:

$user = Get-ADUser -Server global_catalog_server.domain:3268 -Filter {EmailAddress -eq 'john.doe@example.com'}
Set-ADUser -Identity $user.SAMAccountName -Server (Get-ADDomain $user.CanonicalName.Substring(0, $user.CanonicalName.IndexOf('/'))).InfrastructureMaster -Description "test"

Done.

Its also a question of conserving system resources, and I find it more intuitive (of cause that's subjective).

Comment: You're totally right - as long as you only need "read" operation on user. As soon as you include "write", it's not going to work. And I've been clear I need "write".

Comment: "Set-ADUser -Identity $user.SAMAccountName -Server (Get-ADDomain $user.CanonicalName.Substring(0, $user.CanonicalName.IndexOf('/'))).InfrastructureMaster" works.